# Set layer className within event callback in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I'm looking to set a geojson feature's style via setting its `className`.  This works perfectly fine if placed directly on the feature like so:

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.setStyle({className: 'grid-cell'});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

with the style defined in a .css file

```
path.grid-cell{
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #444;
  fill: #aaa;
}
```

However, it does **not** work if added within a feature's event callback:

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.on('click', function(e){
          this.setStyle({className: 'grid-cell'});
          this.bringToFront();
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

What's surprising is that `setStyle({<style_options>});` work in either case for every other [L.path](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path) option *besides* `className`, e.g. `color`, `fillOpacity`, `weight`, etc.

E.g.

```
L.geoJson(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // this works
        layer.setStyle({color: '#faa', fillOpacity: 0.4, weight: 1});

        // this works too
        layer.setStyle({className: 'grid-cell'});

        layer.on('click', function(e){
          // and this works
          layer.setStyle({color: '#afa', fillOpacity: 0.4, weight: 2});

          // BUT THIS DOES NOT WORK
          this.setStyle({className: 'grid-cell'});
          this.bringToFront();
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Any idea what's up here?  [Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQ5vOkcbzH3bQ9CSu4uO?p=preview) illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a discussion of this issue, look here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2662. One of the comments:

> I don't think setStyle should actually change the className. The class is not really a style property, and the logic necessary to handle `leaflet-` classes seems like a hack. I think a `setClassName()` or `add`/`removeClass` API would be more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that makes sense.  It *is* really useful to be able to handle vector styles with .css, rather than burry it in javascript.  I'll keep my eyes open for updates.  Thanks for the reference.